# Docker Windows Error Reporting Crash dump for StackOverflowExceptions not wokring

Tags: docker, .net-core, windows-error-reporting, windows-server-container

I am trying to configure a docker image so that we get a memory dump when a container crashes.

I have configured the registry settings for "Windows Error Reporting" so that it should write a dump file to a mapped directory on the host machine.

```
$key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\{0}" -f CrashTest.exe
New-Item $key -Force
Push-Location $key
New-ItemProperty . -Name DumpType -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord
New-ItemProperty . -Name DumpFolder -Value "C:\Dumps" -PropertyType String
Pop-Location
```

This works fine for an unhandled user exception but not for a stack overflow exception or an out of memory exception.

I have created a github repository with a minimal example of the issue here - https://github.com/spreadex/win-docker-crash-dump

If anyone has any idea how to get this working it would be most appricated.

Cheers.